# Get texcount to ignore numbers

Tags: texcount

Trying to get `texcount` to not count numbers as words, but setting `alphabets=Latin` doesn't seem to be solving the problem. Any suggestions?

MWE:

```
\begin{document}
testing 1 2 3 this should be five
\end{document}
```

`texcount` outputs:

```
  ➜ texcount  FORWORDCOUNT.tex 
  File: FORWORDCOUNT.tex
  Encoding: ascii
  Words in text: 8
  Words in headers: 0
  Words outside text (captions, etc.): 0
  Number of headers: 0
  Number of floats/tables/figures: 0
  Number of math inlines: 0
  Number of math displayed: 0

  ➜ texcount -alphabets=Latin FORWORDCOUNT.tex
  File: FORWORDCOUNT.tex
  Encoding: ascii
  Words in text: 8
  Words in headers: 0
  Words outside text (captions, etc.): 0
  Number of headers: 0
  Number of floats/tables/figures: 0
  Number of math inlines: 0
  Number of math displayed: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, figured it out. Needed to set encoding to `unicode`. This works:

```
  ➜   texcount -alphabets=Latin FORWORDCOUNT.tex -unicode                                          
  File: FORWORDCOUNT.tex
  Words in text: 5
  Words in headers: 0
  Words outside text (captions, etc.): 0
  Number of headers: 0
  Number of floats/tables/figures: 0
  Number of math inlines: 0
  Number of math displayed: 0
```

Comment: Good to hear you worked it out, but specifying `-unicode` shouldn't be necessary (unless something weird is going on that I can't think of). When I try running it with `-alphabets=Latin`, it does not count numbers even if I force it to run encodings other than unicode.

Comment: weird... I'm on a mac running high sierra, texcount 3.0 What are you running?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. I was running TeXcount 3.1, but have tested it on TeXcount 3.0 as well to make sure this is no different. I'm starting to suspect there might be something about how Perl handles strings and Unicode character classes which is different: will have to dig a little deeper to assess that.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

Starting with version 3.2, it is possible to distinguish between words and numbers.

There is a new TeXcount instruction, `%TC:wordtype {original-rule} {wordtype} {new-rule}`, which allows the counting rule to be modified depending on word type: `number`, `mixed` (letters and numbers), or `nonum` (word without any digits).

Add the rule

```
%TC:wordtype text number ignore
```

and words in text be ignored. To do the same for "header words" and "other words", also add the following:

```
%TC:wordtype otherword number ignore
%TC:wordtype headerword number ignore
```

The `text` rule is just and alias for the `word` rule: the other rules also have aliases like `oword` and `hword`.

Beware that this feature is somewhat experimental and may change somewhat in future versions.

---

I'm moving from the comments to an answer, although it's not yet an answer to what is going on.

As mentioned in the comments, the option `-alphabets=Latin` should have worked without the `-unicode` option. When I test this on Windows 10, it works as it should.

The only effect of the `-unicode` option is to ensure the file gets decoded as UTF8, instead of as ASCII which would be the default since the input is pure ASCII. This could influence how the string is represented internally by Perl, but unless you're having an old Perl version, the internal representation should be UTF8.

Could you check which Perl version you run? I'd think `perl --version` should return that you're running some Perl 5 version.

I did some tests with small scripts like this:

```
use Encode;
use Devel::Peek;
my $enc=find_encoding('ascii');
my $x=$enc->decode('test123');
Dump($x);
$x=~s/(\p{Latin})/[$1]/g;
print $x;
```

However, no matter what I did, I couldn't get it to output anything other than `[t][e][s][t]123` indicating that it had correctly identified the Latin letters.

I even tried `my $x=$enc->encode('test123');` which forces a byte representation of `$x` (not with the UTF8 flag set), but it still gave the same result. I thought the Unicode character classes, eg `Latin`, might not work if the string is not in UTF8 representation, but that didn't seem to be a problem; maybe it would be on older/other Perl version.

I've been running TeXcount 3.1 on Windows 10 using Perl 5 (v5.24.0), but checked TeXcount 3.0 as well to make sure there were no relevant changes.

Comment: `perl --version` returns: `This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level`